# Google Analytics - Inpage Analytics - Outbound Link Click Count

Tags: google-analytics, click-counting

I'd like to see how many clicks occur to the "Buy Now" links on my website. Unfortunately, the buy now links are external to my site. There has got to be a way to set up these links so I can see the click count when I view the inpage analytics.

How do you set up Google Analytics so it will track the outbound links and show the click count in the inpage analytics?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use event tracking for this. Here is a simple one using Universal Analytics (with jQuery):

```
jQuery('a.tracklink').on('click', function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'Category', 'Action', 'Label');
});
```

You'll want to change the Category, Action, and Label to properly categorize them in GA. Maybe something like:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Outbound Link', 'Click', 'Buy Now');
```

Others may recommend stopping the propagation of the click action to make sure the tracking goes through (and then forwarding on success), but there are some UX reasons why I'm not a fan of that method. I have not personally run into an issue of the event not being tracked with the above method.

Comment: I have event tracking set up and working. I'm trying to find out if it's possible to see clicks to outbound links (my buynow links) inside the "In-Page Analytics" display. If it is possible then what is the code that needs to be used.

Comment: inpage analytics doesn't display clicks to outbound links, instead you can use google tag manager to track outbound links